# How do I calculate the gas limit for an oraclize query?

Tags: gas, out-of-gas, oracles, gas-limit

I have an oraclize query in my solidity contract and if I don't up the gas limit it doesnt work. My oracalize queries have call backs which call more oraclize queries.

Answer (score 1):

you can look into the gas table maybe this helps you decide:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit?usp=sharing